# Snowflake cron task bug? (Can't do for every x day of month)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I believe there's major flaw in the task scheduling using cron job - correct me if I am wrong or I am missing something:

**Perfectly fine if scheduled on the day of month before desired day of future months (today is 5th and I can schedule task for 6th every mth or any day parameter between 5 to 12)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MYTASK
 WAREHOUSE= XXX
 SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 1 17 6 * * Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
AS CALL SP_ALL_OPS();


ALTER TASK MYTASK RESUME;


select * from table(information_schema.task_history(task_name=>'MYTASK')) WHERE STATE = 'SCHEDULED';
```

**Not fine if scheduled on the day of month before desired day of future months (today is 5th and I CANT schedule for task for 1st every month). TO ADD ON: the task can only accept day between 5 to 12 (exactly 1 week). Numbers beyond this range can't be used at all (BIZARRE BEHAVIOR @@)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MYTASK
 WAREHOUSE= XXX
 SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 1 17 1 * * Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
AS CALL SP_ALL_OPS();


ALTER TASK MYTASK RESUME;


select * from table(information_schema.task_history(task_name=>'MYTASK')) WHERE STATE = 'SCHEDULED';
```

---

Did I do anything wrong?  Let me know if there's solution for this. In such situation I can only schedule task every 1st of the month and to run the desired task on the first run? This doesn't make sense at all as typical linux machine cron job doesn't behave such way. Couldn't find a solution online - so if anyone can shed some lights on this it will be helpful.

### EDIT: "Not fine" here because when I run the task above it doesn't show whether the task has been "scheduled". Good that it's pointed out the query can only 'returns task activity within the last 7 days or the next scheduled execution within the next 8 days'.

Comment: When you say you *CAN'T schedule*, are you getting any error or it just doesn't work?

Comment: @Sergiu, I am not sure if task has been started. It's just that based on task_history - it's not found as 'started'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about scheduling the task. If you run the following command you should be able to see the task and its state will be "STARTED" which means it's scheduled.

```
SHOW TASKS LIKE 'MYTASK';
```

This is about the information_schema.task_history function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html#usage-notes

This function can return all executions run in the **past 7 days** or the next scheduled execution within the **next 8 days.**

Comment: Hi, when I ran this show tasks - I couldn't see my task at all. Do I need to specify schema or warehouse or anything else?

Comment: No you don't need to specify schema. As long as you are in the same database, you should be able to list them. And for the tasks in other databases, you can use "SHOW TASKS IN DATABASE DB_NAME"

Comment: Gotcha - I get what you meant - so technically the 'task_history' will only show tasks going to be run in next 7/8 days but within the 'show tasks' it will show all the tasks that have been scheduled. 

So if I set it to run on the 1st day of month, technically speaking I can run 'task_history' on 25th day of this month, and I can see the scheduled task? Am I right?

Kinda counter-intuitive for such arrangement.

Comment: In this case, please also mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: Hi come to think about it. I can accept the fact that task_history can only show scheduled tasks that's gonna to run between 5th to 12th next month (considering I schedule the task today on 5th) but it's counter intuitive not to show scheduled task gonna to run on 1st next month. I am kinda wondering what's the purpose behind for such design within snowflake for task_history function. Asking from this function design perspective....anyway thanks for your explanation thus far.